# Current Firebase User Returning Nil

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication

I have an app using FirebaseAuth to authenticate users. I do this in an AuthService class;

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseAuth
class AuthService: NSObject {
    
    private override init() {}
    
    static let shared = AuthService()
    
    let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
    var uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    func checkAuthState(completion: @escaping(FirebaseAuth.User?) -> Void) {
//        let listener = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
        Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
            switch user {
            case .none:
                print("USER NOT FOUND IN CHECK AUTH STATE")
                completion(nil)
            case .some(let user):
                print("USER FOUND WITH ID: \(user.uid)")
                completion(user)
            }
        }
//        Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(listener)
    }
}
```

I then sign in a user anonymously using checkAuthState function above. Once this operation completes with some user I perform an action to switch the `rootViewController`.

```
func checkAuthState() {
        authService.checkAuthState { (user) in
            switch user {
            case .none:
                SceneDelegate.shared.rootController.showWelcomeController()
            case .some(_):
                SceneDelegate.shared.rootController.showTabBarController()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code within my `RootViewController`;

```
func showWelcomeController() {
        let welcomeController = WelcomeController(authService: AuthService.shared)
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: welcomeController)
        addChild(navigationController)
        navigationController.view.frame = view.frame
        view.addSubview(navigationController.view)
        navigationController.didMove(toParent: self)
        currentController.willMove(toParent: nil)
        currentController.view.removeFromSuperview()
        currentController.removeFromParent()
        currentController = navigationController
    }
    
    func showTabBarController() {
        let tabBarController = TabBarController()
        addChild(tabBarController)
        tabBarController.view.frame = view.frame
        view.addSubview(tabBarController.view)
        tabBarController.didMove(toParent: self)
        currentController.willMove(toParent: nil)
        currentController.view.removeFromSuperview()
        currentController.removeFromParent()
        currentController = tabBarController
    }
```

The above operates all as expected and shows my `TabBarController`, however, I then run a function in one of my ViewControllers in my TabBarController which is;

```
var uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

func readComments(query: Query, lastDocument: DocumentSnapshot?, completion: @escaping(Result<[CommentModel], NetworkError>) -> ()) {
        guard let uid = auth.uid else { return completion(.failure(.userNotFound)) }
// Other code
```

}

However, I get the .userNotFound error? as it returns nil? I'm confused as checkAuthState is returning a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This typically means that the `currentUser` is not yet initialized by the time that code runs. Since restoring the user's sign-in state requires a call to the server, it is an asynchronous operation.

Any code that depends on the current user state being restored should be inside (or be called from) an `addStateDidChangeListener` as in your first snippet. So you may need a snippet like that in your other view controller(s) too.

Comment: Makes sense. Will try this approach and revert back!

Comment: This works to have a auth listener in each controller. As you rightly said the user still hasn't been initialised yet. My thoughts are either to wait until the user is initialised before showing the next controller or have the listener on each controller (probably best practice if I need to remove a user on the back end)

Comment: On Android I see devs passing the info from one activity into the next one to prevent needing to use another auth state listener. I personally always use an auth state listener though, as it also then forces me to think about what happens if the user gets signed out (for example: you disable their account).